# Как добавить непрозрачность тексту и плавность inoutexpo?

Tags: javascript

Я новичок, и мне нужна помощь даже в элементарных вещах. Как добавить непрозрачность тексту? Что изначально непрозрачность была на 0, а при появлении текста доходила до 100 (полной) непрозрачности? Я пытаюсь вставить, но у меня то анимация текста пропадает, то еще что-то.

```
$(function() {
    // Blasts the title
    var words = $('h1').blast({
      delimiter: 'word'
    });

    words.each(function(i) {
      // Initialization of the position
      $(this).css({
        position: 'relative',
        top: 150,
        opacity: 0,



      })

        .delay(i * 70)

        .animate({top: '0px'}, 400,); 


    });
  });
```

Comment: Вы хотите чтоб текст плавно появлялся или плавно исчезал?

Comment: @Александр, да, чтобы текст плавно появлялся. И при появлении его непрозрачность была на 100%, хотя изначально она на 0.

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут работает: http://jsfiddle.net/vcsr6aqj/21/

```
<div class="text">Тут текст!</div>

.text{
opacity: 0;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.text').velocity('transition.fadeIn', {
        delay: 1000,
        display: null, 
        duration: 2000
    })
});
```

Comment: Так мне нужно, чтобы это было в анимации, которая изложена в вопросе

Comment: Я не знаю зачем вы для этой задачи используете именно Blast.js, если у jquery  есть прекрасный метод fadeTo. Но ответ поправил.